# HTML page content designing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have designed a web application for my school, it has a basic layout structure like navigation bar on the top and a side bar with stacked tabs running towards left and a page content area.
but every time when a user click on one of those stacked tabs the whole page get reloaded, I was wondering if I could load only the page content area while the top navigation bar and side bar should remain constant?
Please help me.. thank you :)

Comment: How familiar are you with javascript? To do that well, you will need to know javascript and php fairly well, you will use a technique called AJAX. If you are not very familiar with javascript or AJAX I highly suggest just allowing the page to reload and don't worry about it.

Comment: yeah I know 'php' and 'javascript' good enough..i'll start with the AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning Ajax techniques will help you.
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ : start with this.